# Choose sounds for push notification in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on app and need to let the user from my settings on app to choose the tone for push notification from system sounds. How to let user open system sounds and choose one for push notification?

Like whatsapp notification settings

Like this link

[link](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/20950116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1:
  Include all possible tones in your app's bundle

Step 2: 
  Allow user to select which tone they want

Step 3:
  Store that on server somewhere

Step 4:
  When pushing that user, include their desired sound in the package

```
aps : {
    alert : "Some Message",
    sound : <#userPreferredSound#>
}
```

Comment: for first step i have to download apple tones and display them ?

Comment: If you want apple's native tones, I believe so (beware of legal issues if you're going to download apple's native sounds).  As far as I know, there's basically two buckets of push tones.  You either use the user default, or include your own sounds in the app bundle.

Comment: I Don't believe this is the right answer, of course whatsapp NOT updating their server everytime some user change his tones. after the payload arriving to the phone, you should customise your notification and show it... I'm facing the same problem, did it in android with an ease, it's much complicated with iOS tho (since I didn't find answers) .

Comment: @XcodeNOOB as far as i know you can't process your app code in time when remote notification arrives and your app is not running. iOS is doing it by itself and play sound file whats name is mentioned in payload and included in your app boundle or default. That is not a case for Android where you can register listener.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to let your server know what sound the user has selected. The notification JSON payload should contain some custom value like "push_sound" for the sound field. Every time a user selects a sound save the newly selected file into 'Library/Sounds' folder and name it "push_sound". That's it