# How to set iOS system alert sounds as push notification sound like Whatsapp does

Tags: ios, push-notification, whatsapp

I'm aware of Apple documentation about setting custom push notification sound for iOS from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html). They said you can set sounds that are located either in app's **main bundle** or in **Library/Sounds** folder from app's data container.

However, as can be seen in the images below, WhatsApp for iOS allows the user to select sounds that are the same as alert system sound for iOS, for example, popcorn, circles and so on.

[image: WhatsApp settings]

[image: WhatsApp sounds list]

My question is, is there a way to use system sounds for push notifications alert or WhatsApp just copy/paste the same sounds to its main bundle?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I haven't. I think they use system sounds, something like that https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary, but I'm not sure.
In my case, I just copied and pasted sounds to my app's bundle.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you have to just copy/paste the same sounds to your app's main bundle. However, be careful about the legal issues of the sounds you use.
There is also a question's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27460211/4369441) where you might find how to do it.